# Linear Algebra: Image and surjective function

Tags: linear-algebra

The linear transformation $T : U \to V$ is injective if and only if $\ker(T) = \{0_U\}$. It is surjective if and only if $\mbox{Im}(T) = V$.

I find the proof straightforward for the first however I cannot find anywhere a proof for the second statement, namely "It is surjective if and only if $\mbox{Im}(T)=V$".
Can anyone provide me with such a proof or help me find one?

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of definition

$$\text{Im}(T)=\{v\in V:v=T(u)\text{ for some } u\in U\}$$
So if this set is equal to $V$, then for every $v\in V$ there is some $u\in U$ such that $f(u)=v$. That is the definition of surjectivity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems trivial. $T$ is surjective if for any $v \in V$, there's a $u \in U$ such that $T(u) = v$. But your definition of $\mbox{Im}\,(T)$ is probbaly something like:
$$\mbox{Im}\,(T) = \left\{ v \in V \, \vert \, v = T(u), u \in U  \right\} $$

---

I'll elaborate to make it more explicit.

If $\mbox{Im}\,(T) = V$ and you want to show that $T$ is surjective, pick an arbitrary $v \in V$. Because $\mbox{Im}\,(T) = V$, you have $v \in \mbox{Im}\,(T)$ so there is a $u \in U$ such that $T(u) = v$. This makes $T$ surjective.

If $T$ is surjective, pick (again) an arbitrary $v \in V$. Because $T$ is surjective, there is a $u \in U$ such that $T(u) = v$. But then $v$ is also in $\mbox{Im}\,(T)$, according to the definition of the image of $T$.